# create xml schema collection maximum value of fractionDigits restriction

Tags: sql-server, xsd

I'm trying to load third party XSD Scheme to my SQL Server 2008 throught "create xml schema collection" statement

There is a complex type based on "xs:decimal" with restrictions:

```
        <xs:totalDigits value="31"/>
        <xs:fractionDigits value="14"/>
```

inside the XSD.

And SQL Server returns error

```
Msg 6960, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Component 'NAME' is outside of allowed range. Maximum for 'fractionDigits' is 10 and maximum number of digits for non fractional part is 28
```

But I still able to create a variable with type "numeric(31,14)"

I didn't find any restrictions neither on w3c documentations nor in MSDN. Can you please guide me to some documentation on this restrictions. May be I can fix it with some Service Pack or Setting.

SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64)   Sep 21 2011 22:45:45   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

---

I found an answer on the MSDN ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190665(v=sql.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190665%28v=sql.100%29.aspx))

> SQL Server does not support variable precision decimals. The
>   xs:decimal type represents arbitrary precision decimal numbers.
>   Minimally conforming XML processors must support decimal numbers with
>   a minimum of totalDigits=18. SQL Server supports totalDigits=38, but
>   limits the fractional digits to 10. All xs:decimal instanced values
>   are represented internally by the server by using the SQL type numeric
>   (38, 10).

They map xs:decimal not to *numeric* type, but *decimal*

Comment: I have not found any documentation from Microsoft about the limitation but it is mentioned in [The Art of XSD SQL Server XML Schema Collections](http://assets.red-gate.com/community/books/assets/the-art-of-xsd.pdf) by Jacob Sebastian (page 489). It is the same in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Please add the solution as a proper answer to your own question and mark it as the answer instead of editing your question. This will signal to future readers that the question actually -has- a solution. =)

Comment: I will do it with pleasure, but i can't now (there is a few restrictions for new users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer on the MSDN ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190665(v=sql.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190665%28v=sql.100%29.aspx))

> SQL Server does not support variable precision decimals. The
>   xs:decimal type represents arbitrary precision decimal numbers.
>   Minimally conforming XML processors must support decimal numbers with
>   a minimum of totalDigits=18. SQL Server supports totalDigits=38, but
>   limits the fractional digits to 10. All xs:decimal instanced values
>   are represented internally by the server by using the SQL type numeric
>   (38, 10).

They map xs:decimal not to *numeric* type, but *decimal*